# (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 8 column 8

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

## CI Setup

i am trying to configure a yml in this format but i got some issues like :(): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 8 column 8.

```
    include:
      - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

    variables:
      SAST_GOSEC_LEVEL: 2

    spotbugs-sast:
     stage: QA
      rules:
         if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
         if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

```
ERROR: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 8 column 8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `rules` must be at the same indentation as `stage`. If it is more indented, it counts as part of the value started with `QA`, which leads to this error since YAML does not allow multi-line scalars to be a key of a mapping (indicated by `:` after `rules`).
- `rules` must be a sequence.

So the fixed YAML is:

```yaml
include:
  - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  SAST_GOSEC_LEVEL: 2

spotbugs-sast:
  stage: QA
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```